# How do you connect a log in system to PyGame?

Tags: javascript, python, php, mysql, pygame

I am creating a platform game on PyGame. I have created the main aspects of the game, such as the levels and the player etc. Which all works :) But I am trying to add a login system. I know how to create login systems with PHP and JavaScript but I don't know how to connect that to pygame :) I could use MySQL but I don't know how to connect that either :)

Thank you :)

Comment: No, I had all ready read that post. thank you though :)

Comment: Perhaps clarify how it does not answer your question then? So far the question is broad enough to warrant an entire book for an answer.